# Writing first Android app, stuck trying to simply run the Hello World tutorial

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to Java, haven't used Eclipse in probably 2 years. We're starting up a mobile dev team at work, and I'm just going over the tutorials on the Android site:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

Simply just created a project, launched the virtual device manager, have that emulator running, then click Run -> Run as Android application in Eclipse .

I've been staring at this screen for about 5 minutes now:

[image]

It says "Launching (100%)" in the bottom right corner of eclipse, and this Progres window just says Launching, but the emulator isn't doing anything.

I know emulators are generally pretty slow... But is this normal or did I do something wrong?

Comment: You should make a run configuration for the project, it doesn't necessarily connect to the device you have running?

Comment: The run configurations are under the Run menu in the menu bar btw

Comment: Well, it's set to automatically pick an AVD. Ended up just killed the process (I couldn't close it normally) and re-creating a new project and it ran much more quickly. Very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happened to me too, and still does at times:

- Close the emulator and execute the program again
- If that didn't work, execute the program while the emulator is running. A new emulator will pop up, close the old emulator
- If that didn't work, delete device and create a new one.

Also, is there anything at all popping up on the Logcat view?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand checking the list of process afterwards. Sometimes when i brutally terminate an app in eclipse, the process is still running. 
But i'm on PC and i use an older version. Maybe it has been fixed.